# SwiftUI Extra arguments at positions #11, #12 in call

Tags: ios, swiftui

Im having this error where at " Button(action: { " xcode says "Extra arguments at positions #11, #12 in call".

I am importing all the assets and aligning them and stuff

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var Index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
      
        VStack{
            
            Spacer()
            
            CustomTabs(index: self.$Index)
        }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CustomTabs : View {
    
    @Binding var index: Int
    
    var body: some View{
    
        HStack{
        
            Button(action: {  

                   
                self.index = 0
            
            }) {
        
               Image("home")
            }
            foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(self.index == 0 ? 1 : 0.1))
            
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Button(action: {
                
                self.index = 1
            
            }) {
        
               Image("coins")
            }
            foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(self.index == 1 ? 1 : 0.1))
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Button(action: {
                
                self.index = 2
            
            }) {
        
               Image("bulleted list")
            }
            foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(self.index == 2 ? 1 : 0.1))
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Button(action: {
                
                self.index = 3
            
            }) {
        
               Image("dots")
            }
            foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(self.index == 3 ? 1 : 0.1))
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
    
            
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling foregroundColor incorrectly.

As it is a function, You have to call it with dot `.` notation to the view.

```
Button(action: {
    self.index = 0
}) {

   Image("home")
}
.foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(self.index == 0 ? 1 : 0.1)) //<< here with . notation
```

Fixes this for all your buttons and your code compiles